# Animate sibling element

Tags: angular, angular-animations

In my app I've 2 sibling element. One element is hidden and I can toggle it's visibility by button. I've added an animation, when this hidden element become visible. The problem is, the sibling element doesn't animate. It just jumps to it's new position. Any idea how to fix this? See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u6ptes) example.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { animate, style, transition, trigger } from "@angular/animations";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css',],
  animations: [
      trigger(
          "enterAnimation", [
              transition(":enter", [
                  style({transform: "translateY(-100%)", opacity: 0}),
                  animate("500ms", style({transform: "translateY(0)", opacity: 1}))
              ]),
              transition(":leave", [
                  style({transform: "translateY(0)", opacity: 1}),
                  animate("500ms", style({transform: "translateY(-100%)", opacity: 0}))
              ])
          ]
      )
  ],
})
export class AppComponent  {
  visible: boolean = false;

  toggle(): void {
    this.visible = !this.visible;
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="box1" *ngIf="visible" [@enterAnimation]></div>
<div class="box2"></div>

<button (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of using transform use height to get that effect. [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxmyai?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
trigger(
          "enterAnimation", [
              transition(":enter", [
                  style({height: "0px", opacity: 0}),
                  animate("500ms", style({height: "50px", opacity: 1}))
              ]),
              transition(":leave", [
                  style({height: "50px", opacity: 1}),
                  animate("500ms", style({height: "0px", opacity: 0}))
              ])
          ]
      )
```

Comment: Is there a proper way to achieve this?(other than the height animation, which seems non-smooth)

Comment: you can always go with css transition animation if looks not that smooth https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gvzz8a